# Converting Graph weights to Matrix in python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, graph

I have data in the form of:

```
A=B=11
A=C=6
A=D=5
B=C=19
B=D=17
C=D=6
```

But I'd like to convert this into this format:

```
graph= [[ 0, 10, 15, 20 ],
            [ 10, 0, 35, 25 ],
            [ 15, 35, 0, 30 ],
            [ 20, 25, 30, 0 ]]
```

How is this achieved? I'm aware of how multi-dimensional arrays work however constructing this matrix using python is quite confusing

Comment: Do you want to data to be a list or a string that hold the definition of a list inside?

Comment: The data should be in a list in order to construct the graph

Comment: Could you explain how you get the values in the graph 0, 10, 15, 20...

Comment: Is the data stored in a file?

Comment: They're random values, I just used those numbers as an example @TheRavenSpectre

Comment: @user2246849 Yes, the data is stored in a separate file which I plan on importing before the conversion happens

Comment: Could you then provide the actual data/a smaller sample of the data and the eventual result that you want as it allows us to understand what you want better

Comment: *"They're random values*": how is that helpful? Could you please provide input and output that relate to eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to make an adjacency list. Then enumerate the keys of that dictionary to define an index for each key. Then finally copy the weights into the final matrix structure:

```
nodes = {}
for line in open("input.txt").read().splitlines():
    a, b, weight = line.split("=")
    nodes.setdefault(a, []).append((b, int(weight)))
    nodes.setdefault(b, []).append((a, int(weight)))

n = len(nodes)
key2index = { key: i for i, key in enumerate(nodes.keys()) }
graph = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
for a, edges in nodes.items():
    row = graph[key2index[a]]
    for b, weight in edges:
        row[key2index[b]] = weight

print(graph)
```

A zero in the matrix denotes there is no edge, like is the case in your example on the main diagonal of the matrix (i.e. your example graph has no "loops").

#### Comment

As you asked in a deleted comment to skip the first line of the file, here is the code adapted to do just that:

```
nodes = {}
lines = open("input.txt").read().splitlines()
for line in lines[1:]:
    a, b, weight = line.split("=")
    nodes.setdefault(a, []).append((b, int(weight)))
    nodes.setdefault(b, []).append((a, int(weight)))

n = len(nodes)
key2index = { key: i for i, key in enumerate(nodes.keys()) }
graph = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
for a, edges in nodes.items():
    row = graph[key2index[a]]
    for b, weight in edges:
        row[key2index[b]] = weight

print(graph)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Change to your filename.
filename = 'graph.csv'

# Lines to skip.
skip_rows = 1

# Whether the graph is undirected. 
undirected = True

# Read file and convert vertex names to integer indices. Names are sorted. 
# I.e., A=0, B=1, etc. (like in your example).
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='=', header=None, names=['n1', 'n2', 'weight'], skiprows=skip_rows)
cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=sorted(np.unique(np.concatenate((df['n1'].unique(), df['n2'].unique())))), ordered=True)
df['n1'] = df['n1'].astype(cat_type).cat.codes
df['n2'] = df['n2'].astype(cat_type).cat.codes

n_nodes = len(cat_type.categories)
graph = np.full((n_nodes, n_nodes), np.nan)

for n1, n2, w in zip(df['n1'], df['n2'], df['weight']):
    graph[n1, n2] = w
    if undirected:
        graph[n2, n1] = w

np.fill_diagonal(graph, 0)

print(graph)
```

```
[[ 0. 11.  6.  5.]
 [11.  0. 19. 17.]
 [ 6. 19.  0.  6.]
 [ 5. 17.  6.  0.]]
```

If `graph[i, j] == NaN`, it means there is no edge (path of length 1) from node `i` to node `j` as per your file.

Comment: Do you know how I could skip reading the first line of the file?

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy I edited my answer to skip a line (see `skip_rows`).